# How to set socketTimeout in Slick for MySQL connection?

Tags: scala, slick, hikaricp

HikariCP is used in Slick 3 library for configuration of Connection Pool.

According to [HikariCP Rapid-Recovery](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Rapid-Recovery%20sokcet%20time) in order to be able "to recover from database restart or network partition events" its recommended to set [socketTimeout as its disabled by default.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.htm)

Question is how to setup socketTimeout in slick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In application.conf add socketTimeout as part of JDBC URL

```
db {
  profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
  db {
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?socketTimeout=30000"
    driver = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    user = "<user>"
    password = "<password>"
  }
}
```

From [MySQL Connector/J 8.0 documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.htm)

> Configuration properties can be set in one of
>   the following ways:
>
> - Using the set*() methods on MySQL implementations of jdbc url
>     java.sql.DataSource (which is the preferred method when using
>     implementations of java.sql.DataSource)
> - As a key-value pair in the java.util.Properties instance passed to DriverManager.getConnection() or Driver.connect()
> - As a JDBC URL parameter in the URL